# Can i say "if your var1 = yes and var2 = yes" then do something?

Tags: python

The following program should help predicting your future Job via a few nested `if`-statements.

```
print("This app will predict which job suits you best")
ComputerProgramer = input("Are you good at coding. A)Yes. B)No. [A/B]")
if ComputerProgramer == "A":
    ComputerProgramer = "Yes"
else :
    ComputerProgramer = "No"

Architect = input("Are you good at drawing. A)Yes. B)No. [A/B]")
if Architect == "A":
    Architect = "Yes"
elif Architect == "Yes", ComputerProgramer == "Yes"  :
    FinalAnswer = input("which one do you prefer? A)coding. B)drawing. [A/B]")
    if FinalAnswer == "A":
        print("Computer Programer")
    else :
        print("Architect")
else :
    Architict = "no"
```

Can you please help me find a replacement for this: 
`elif Architect == "Yes", ComputerProgramer == "Yes" :` ?

Comment: `Architect == ComputerProgramer == "Yes" `

Comment: Use `and` instead of `,`. Also, the condition `elif Architect == "Yes", ComputerProgramer == "Yes"  :` can _never_ be true, as the `elif` is only checked if the user did not enter `"A"`. Also, why not have the user enter `"yes"` or `"no"` in the first place? Also, better use boolean `True` and `False` instead of `"yes"` and `"no"`.

Comment: either what @Chris_Rands said or 'Architect == "Yes" and ComputerProgramer == "Yes' (for if you might have different checks you want to perform.

Comment: @tobias_k `elif Architect == "Yes", ComputerProgramer == "Yes"` can never be **`False`**. it is always `True`, since all two-tuples are `True` (If it even was a valid syntax that is). This can be seen with `elif (Architect == "Yes", ComputerProgramer == "Yes")`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @DeepSpace Only with `(..., ...)`; without, it's a syntax error. But I meant after replacing the `,` with `and` anyways.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that *isn't* legal syntax, as there doesn't seem to be anything else to interpret a comma-separate list between `if` and `:` as *except* a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `and`. Your code could then look like this:

```
computerProgramer = input("Are you good at coding. A)Yes. B)No [A/B]")
if computerProgramer == "A":
    computerProgramer = "Yes"

architect = input("Are you good at drawing. A)Yes . B)no. [A/B]")
if architect == "A":
    architect = "Yes"

if (architect == "Yes") and (computerProgramer == "Yes")  :
    finalAnswer = input("which one do you prefer? A)coding B)drawing [A/B]")
    if FinalAnswer == "A":
        print("Computer Programer")
    else :
        print("Architect")
```

Note: I changed your `elif` to a new `if`, since else would not have been excuteted after `"A"` as answer. ([may read this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements))

> Furthermore, as Chris_Rands suggested, in this case you can simplify the if-statement with: `if architect == computerProgramer == "Yes": ...`